# ACL is NOT enabled but it's working

Tags: mount, fstab, debian, acl

How this is possible?

1. ACL is not enabled in `/etc/fstab`, and I can verify it via manually opening `fstab` or running `sudo mount | grep -i acl`.
2. But `getfacl` & `setfacl` Commands would work without any complains!

The problem is, first I need to understand why this is working, and second I need to check other systems to see if ACL support is available on them or not, so how can I do that?

ACL commands were tested on both `/` & `/mydrive`(see below for `mount` output).

OS Info:

`uname -a`:
`Linux localhost 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a`:
`No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)
Release:    7.5
Codename:   wheezy`

`mount`:
`sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=384309,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=308664k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3180f94a-e765-44e9-93f7-33aa1c6422c0 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1188500k)
/dev/sda5 on /mydrive type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ext*3/4* file systems have a *default mount options* attribute in their headers. You can see it with:

```
$ LC_ALL=C tune2fs -l /dev/device | grep 'Default mount options:'
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

You can change it with `tune2fs -o` and mounting with `-o noacl` would override it.

When creating a new file system, `mke2fs` will set that based on what you specify in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`. For instance, mine has:

```
[defaults]
[...]
        default_mntopts = acl,user_xattr
[...]
```

However, as [noted by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136171/acl-is-not-enabled-but-its-working/136182?noredirect=1#comment217174_136182), since 2.6.39, `acl` and `user_xattr` are on by default (provided support has been enabled in the kernel at compile time which would generally be the default). So even without the `acl` default mount option, `acl`s would be enabled by default on newer kernel, and the only way to disable it would be to use `mount -o noacl`.

To check whether ACLs are supported, best would be to try and query them:

```
$ chacl -l /the/mountpoint
chacl: cannot get access ACL on '/the/mountpoint': Operation not supported
```

Comment: @Gilles, Thanks. Answer updated, however note that `tune2fs -o noacl` doesn't work and `noacl` in `/etc/mke2fs.conf` is ignored (at least with e2fsprogs 1.42.10)

Comment: The default mount options in the superblock are stored in a bitfield , which means it can not hold arbitrary values, and "noacl" isn't part of the list. Newer file systems support a `mount_opts` attribute that stores strings.

Comment: @Bachsau, there is a EXT4_DEFM_XATTR_USER in the superblock's default mount options, but since 2.6.39, that's ignored as acl is now defaulted on. The `mount_opts` you're refering to are the options handled by the FS *driver*. One of them is noacl so the user can tell the driver to disable ACLs for the mount of that FS.